# Prevent Postgresql from running at startup

Tags: mac, postgresql

At some point in the past, I had installed posgresql and I can't get rid of it:

```
$ ps -A|egrep postg   232 ??        
287 ??         0:00.02 postgres: logger process                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
328 ??         0:00.09 postgres: writer process                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
335 ??         0:00.06 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
336 ??         0:00.03 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                                                                                                                                          
342 ??         0:00.01 postgres: stats collector process
```

I'd like to stop it from starting up every time I boot, since `fs_usage` shows it keeps my disk occupied.

I've already tried adding `POSTGRES=-NO-` in `/etc/hostconfig`, but the processes keep spawing.

Also I've tried something I found on another post, with no luck:

```
$: locate postg|egrep plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-8.4.plist
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/StartupItems/postgresql-8.3/StartupParameters.plist

$: sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-8.4.plist

(restart)
```

But still postgresql processes show up :(

Answer (score 40):

Note that with PostgreSQL 9.0 (and probably newer) on Mac OS 10.6.8 (and probably older), in order to prevent the PostgreSQL server from auto-starting, you have to:

1. Go to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
2. Open `com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist` in an editor as `root` (replace `9.0` with your correct version number), e.g. `sudo vim com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist`.
3. Locate the line `<key>RunAtLoad</key>`
4. Change the next line from `<true/>` to `<false/>`
5. Save and exit.

That should do it. Also, if you want to stop the server immediately, without restarting, `su` to `postgres` and run `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg_ctl stop -D<your data dir>`. You can find out which is your current data dir with `ps aux|grep postgre`.

Source: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2240.page#8321

Comment: `com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist` wasn't found at this location for me.

Comment: @AlecRust Did you locate it? Try `ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons/*postgre*` to see if it's not a different version of PostgreSQL you're using.

Comment: I've looked within `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, no mention of postgres (note: installed through Homebrew). Using [PostgreSQL Mac Preferences](https://github.com/mckenfra/postgresql-mac-preferences) in the end to manage this.

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me

```
cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/
sudo rm com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

In Mac OSX: (Assuming Default Locations)

Via uninstaller:

1. In the installation directory, there will be a uninstall-`postgresql.app` file will be there, executing (double clicking) that will uninstall the postgresql installation.

Manual Uninstallation:

1. Stop the server

`sudo /sbin/SystemStarter stop postgresql-8.3`

2. Remove menu shortcuts:

`sudo rm -rf /Applications/PostgreSQL 8.3`

3. Remove the ini file

`sudo rm -rf /etc/postgres-reg.ini`

4. Removing Startup Items

`sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/postgresql-8.3`

5. Remove the data and installed files

`sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL/8.3`

6. Delete the user postgres

`sudo dscl . delete /users/postgres`

Answer (score 0):

Search for the below packaged file name

```
    com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist
```

This will be found at cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/.Remove it if you don't need.From the
    Question perspective make changes to true to false at  **RunAtLoad**

It works like a charm for me

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.